# How to Unit Test WCF Soap Response Request/Reply

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, request

I haven't found this in 1+ hour of searching, so here goes. 
I have a WCF request/reply service, and the messages(both request and reply) are defined as MessageContracts.

My question is, given a complete soap message, how can I unit test (from a string for instance) the response portion of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to mock the response (since you don't need to be testing the WCF code). There are several mocking frameworks available for .Net. I'm partial to [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks), but there is also [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), which I don't know a whole lot about. I'm sure there are others, but those are the two that come readily to mind.